# getActionBar() returns null in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

getActionBar() returns null in android, code is given below

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
    if(actionBar!=null){
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)this    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_test, null);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
    }
```

and my theme for actionbar is this

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
<!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item> -->

</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"> 
  <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item> 
  <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item> 
  <item name="android:background">#4C4B4B</item> 
  <item name="android:actionBarSize">150dp</item>
  <item name="android:height">50sp</item>
 </style> 

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" 
  parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"> 
  <item name="android:textColor">#FFF</item> 
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
  <item name="android:textSize">24dip</item> 
</style> 

<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" 
  parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"> 
  <item name="android:textColor">#F0F</item> 
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
  <item name="android:textSize">24dip</item> 
</style>
```

this returns null in the main activity. here MainActivity extending Activity, not ActionBarActivity. I changed to some other theme but unfortunately i couldn't get the right one. please help me

Comment: Did you tried getSupportActionBar() ?

Comment: but i used the mainactivity extends Activity instead of ActionBarActivity. is it possible to use getSupportActionBar() in extending Activity without changing it?

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
 <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
 <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

hope it will help you